# Node error trying to run yeoman

Tags: node.js, yeoman

I am trying to use yeoman to scaffold for a webapp. when I try and do anything with node I get error thrown. Below is my command line output when I try and 'update node' and when i try and run 'yo webapp'. Can anyone help point out the error?

```
$ node update

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module     '/Users/william/wdi/pixelect_project/pixelect_client_server/update'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3


$ yo webapp

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'inquirer'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/lib/index.js:9:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem. I my case helped this: **npm install -g yo**

Answer (score 1):

For me this is also happening with other node apps as well (eg. grunt and gulp).
Reinstalling it does the trick. In this case you have to reinstall generator-webapp (npm install -g generator-webapp). If after reinstalling generator you get the same message than reinstall yeoman as levon suggested.